# Design pattern to register handler (provider) to handle types of requests

Tags: php, design-patterns

I have scenario where I have collection of objects. Data of different  objects are stored in different data sources. I am looking for design pattern to register data providers (Already have multiple data providers) for different objects. I need flexibility to add new type of objects and register handler to fetch data for those objects.

E.g. I need to display list of cities. I have city information in mysql city table. e.g. id, name, state, country. I need to display weather information as well which comes from 3rd party service. I also need to display some other information which is stored in mongo. e.g. population, literacy rate etc.

I need to fetch all above data from different data providers and display in tabular form. I need flexibility to add more type of such data.

There are several patterns which I think can be used to solve some part of problem e.g. command pattern, observer pattern, chain of responsibility, strategy etc.

I would like the code to be

```
$objects = [$cityMetadata, $weather, $demographic];

$dataProviderRegistry->register($cityMedatadaProvider);
$dataProviderRegistry->register($weatherDataProvider);
$dataProviderRegistry->register($demographicDataProvider);       

foreach ($objects as $object) {
   $data = $dataProviderRegistry->get($object);
}
```

I would like DataProviderRegistry to select correct provider for object  registered to handle that type of object. I should be able to register new type of provider in registry to handle new types of objects.

I am not sure how one or more type of design patterns can be applied to solve this specific problem.

```
class WeatherDataProvider
{
     public function getType()
    {
        return "Weather";
    }

    public function getData()
    {
        //fetch data
    }

}


Class Weather 
{

     public function getType()
    {
        return "Weather";
    }    

}

class DataProviderRegistry
{

    private $providers = [];

    public function register(DataProviderInterface $provider)
    {
        $this->providers[$provider->getType()] = $provider;
    }

    public function get($object)
    {
        return $this->providers[$object->getType()]->getData();
    }
}
```

Comment: Strategy design pattern comes to mind at this time, could you give a more concrete example/s of the data and expected results

Comment: yeah had thought of strategy to select provider but since there is loop for multiple objects & registration of objects, wasnt sure how to use it here. Will add to question.

Comment: I meant composite objects (not aggregate) but anyway that is not relevant for the problem. so its fine to remove.

Comment: @vishal Please don't delete questions with a significant answer already given. It goes against being useful as a Q&A repository, and is also rude towards the person who spent time writing an answer for you ;).

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I felt question is incomplete causing confusion, thought better to rewrite with some example. Answer given doesn't solve my problem may be because question is not put it in right way. If it update same question, answer may become not much relevant to what i need.

Comment: added example & tried to explain problem further

Answer (score 2):

I would just create a [repository](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) (or probably - multiple ones), that would mask the logic for choosing correct [data mapper](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) for each entity (business object object). You do not need to even implement the full repository. Just do the relevant part for you and leave out things like identity-map, if it is not currently needed.

You can even set it up so that, when entity is being saved or populated, the "repository" picks the matching data mapper. based on `get_class($entity)`. That way you will be able simplify the external interface even further.

And in each data mapper you can put code for working with whatever persistence abstraction that you need to (sql, cache, rest, etc.).

#### TL;DR

Use the repository pattern as the basis and then mutate it according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks, repositories are already there, I am using doctrine (so data mapper as well). The problem is fetching data from different data sources so choosing different providers (repositories) & flexibility to add more type of data without changing existing code (Open-Close principle). I should add example to clarify the problem.

Comment: What I was talking about was unrelated to any ORM. I don't even you can do any of that "multiple data source" stuff if you insists on using an ORM.

Comment: yeah understand, but doesnt ORM provide repositories & data mapper out of the box ?  DataProvider will be abstraction over any type of database abstraction layer (ORM  or some data from mongo or some other source, so there will be multiple providers.)

Comment: Design patterns are not something, that "gets provided", but instead are shorthand descriptions of the implementation and intent for some piece of code. Just because Doctrine has repositories and mappers does not mean, that those are exactly the same as what you need (it's actually a safe bet, that they are not).  As I see it, a good ORM is a form of *technical debt*. You use it to quickly get a project running. When it starts limiting your options, you begin to look at ways to get rid of it. Instead of trying to glue another layer of abstraction on top of it to hide the ugliness underneath.